# MySql Movie Reservation System Design

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have the following pseudo MySQL for a movie reservation system:

Table Movie:

```
    id int auto_increment not null,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    .....
```

Table MovieSched:

```
    movie_id foreign key refers to Movie,
    sched_id int auto increment,
    date & time,
    max_size
```

Table MovieSchedSignUp:

```
    sched_id,
    user_id
```

Every movie schedule has a max_size of users who can sign up. To register a user, I insert a row in MovieSchedSignUp.

The problem is: How do I insert a row in MovieSchedSignUp while ensuring the schedule is not "overbooked" (sign ups <= max_size)

Specifically, to register a user for a schedule, what is the query I should use, and how do I check whether the schedule is full or not (so I can tell the user whether registration is successful)? Note that these requires some sort of atomic operation, a transaction perhaps.

What is the most efficient way to go about doing this?

Comment: How about counting the number of rows for the scheduled movie in `MovieSchedSignUp`?

Comment: A trigger on an insert on `MovieSchedSignUp` that inserts the registration status into some table (Should be there even before PHP 'knows' the query is done). After inserting, poll the table a couple of times with a couple of ms interval (just in case), and you will know if the registration failed or not. All through AJAX so that the user won't notice any of it, except a spinner. Sound okay? Or maybe a [stored procedure](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php)

Comment: I would be tempted to use a transaction (if available in the storage engine in use) and check the count, and insert if possible. Failing that do an insert based on a select returning fixed values (that you want to insert) and a check against the table.

Answer (score 0):

Rough idea for SQL:-

```
INSERT INTO Table MovieSchedSignUp (sched_id, user_id)
SELECT '$move_sched_id', '$user_id'
FROM 
(
    SELECT sched_id, COUNT(*) AS BookingCount
    FROM MovieSchedSignUp
    WHERE sched_id = '$move_sched_id'
    GROUP BY sched_id
    HAVING BookingCount < $max_size
)
```

Insert a record based on a select. The select returns 2 fixed values, and selects from a sub query that returns the schedule id if the number of bookings is less than the max number of bookings.

Comment: If you use something like this then you don't need to wrap it in a transaction. You probably will need to check the affected rows to know whether it has inserted a record. Further it will require a bit more playing with if you want to insert multiple rows

Comment: Aye. It will only insert a row if the number of existing bookings for that schedule id is less than the max number of bookings allowed.