# MySQL movie reservation system design part 2

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

This is similar to another question but not entirely the same.

My aim is to design a movie reservation system. A user could click on one or more empty seats for a movie schedule to reserve them. But he needs to make a payment before 15mins is up, otherwise the reserved seats would have to be ***automatically*** given up for other users.

I have the following pseudo MySQL :

Table Movie:

```
    id        int primary key,
    name      varchar,
    .....
```

Table MovieSched:

```
    movie_id       foreign key refers to Movie,
    sched_id       int primary key,
    showtime       datetime,         // date and time of schedule
    count_signup   int,              // number of sign ups
    max_size       int               // max number of seats
```

Table MovieSchedSignUp:

```
    sched_id  foreign key refers to MovieSched,
    user_id   foreign key refers to User,
    signup    datetime              // datetime of signup
```

Every movie schedule has a `max_size` of users who can sign up. To register a user, I insert a row in MovieSchedSignUp with the current date and time.

A few constraints naturally arise from the requirements:

1. Due to possible inconsistency between the interface and database, I need to inform a user A when there are not enough seats available when A tries to reserve seats. (for e.g., another user B could have bought all the seats right before A.)
2. I need to ***atomically*** insert a row in MovieSchedSignUp while ensuring the schedule is not "overbooked" (`count_signup` <= `max_size`) as well as updating `count_signup` at the same time.
3. I need to ensure payment is made within 15mins, otherwise the reserved seats have to be freed.

My thoughts are:

1. Have extra columns  in MovieSchedSignUp to keep track of when payment is made.
2. Use a transaction, ***but how do I return information about whether there are enough seats or not***?
3. Have a batch job running in the background to delete the "expired" rows in MovieSchedSignUp.

What is the most efficient way to go about doing this? Any other thoughts? Don't really want to use a batch job, but is there any other way out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql Movie Reservation System Design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988257/mysql-movie-reservation-system-design)

Comment: This should belong on programmers as it has to do with planning and not implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this situation you are going to have to use a transaction.

1. Start the transaction
2. Insert the records to be added to a temp table
3. Do a join between the temp table, MovieSched and MovieSchedSignUp to
   check the number of records (combined temp and MovieSchedSignUp) isn't greater than max size.
4. If OK then do the insert
5. If OK them commit the transaction, if not then roll back the
   transaction.